# What does 'npm cache clean' clean?

Tags: npm, npm-cache

`npm cache clean [-f]` should clean the cache dir (oh yes)

But when I check my ~/.npm dir before and after the cleaning, the content is exactly the same.

So my questions are:

1. Which dir is cleaned when I run that cmd?
2. What is the ~/.npm dir?

Comment: [*"npm stores cache data in an opaque directory within the configured **cache**, named **_cacache**"*](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache.html)

Comment: yeah, I've read it too, but the issue is that the cmd above doesn't delete that _cacache dir.

Comment: It doesn't claim to *delete* that directory, but to *clear* it - are you saying nothing changes inside that whole tree?

Comment: Indeed. Where can I find exact definition of the "clear" action?